# In C#, how to set all tree nodes checked true just after treeview loaded

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, treeview, treenode

I have a `TreeView` in a `WindowForm` build in C#. In that **treeview**, files are being loaded successfully. I've also implemented checkboxes, showing in front of each tree node.

Now, I want all **checkboxes** to be **checked true by default** after all directories are loaded in **treeview**. 
I tried the following code but no luck. It just checks true only the root node, not all the sub-nodes. 
The first method `btnDirectoryPath_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` is for button click which selects the path of the directory being loaded. From here, I am calling `setAllCheckedTrue(TreeView treeView1)`

```
private void btnDirectoryPath_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = txtDirectoryPath.Text;
            DialogResult drResult = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (drResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                txtDirectoryPath.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;

                // Setting Inital Value of Progress Bar
                progressBar1.Value = 0;
                // Clear All Nodes if Already Exists
                treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
                toolTip1.ShowAlways = true;
                if (txtDirectoryPath.Text != "" && Directory.Exists(txtDirectoryPath.Text))
                {
                    //Loading all directories and sub directories and files
                    LoadDirectory(txtDirectoryPath.Text);
                    //setting all checkboxes true by default on loading.
                    setAllCheckedTrue(treeView1);
                }
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Select Directory!!");
            }
        }

private void setAllCheckedTrue(TreeView treeView1)
        {
            foreach(TreeNode treeNode in treeView1.Nodes)
            {
                treeNode.Checked = true;
            }
        }
```

Following is snapshot of my treeview -

[image: Snapshot of my treeview]

Another doubt is, How to handle **on treeview load event**? Is there any specific thing in c# to detect treeview load event?

I am a beginner to C#, Please help me out if possible. Thanks!

Comment: Update the function "setAllCheckedTrue" to treat nodes that have child nodes. after the line "treeNode.Checked = true;" , add the current line: if (treeNode.Nodes.Count > 0) ){setAllCheckedTrue(treeNode)}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a recursive function to check all the subnodes as well. The TreeView does not do this automatically.
You also have to consider how to handle the update of parent nodes, when you unselect a subnode.

Try something like this for setting the subnodes as well:

```
private void SetAllCheckedTrue(TreeView treeView1)
{
    foreach(TreeNode treeNode in treeView1.Nodes)
    {
          SetTreeNodeCheckbox(treeNode , true);
    }
}

private void SetTreeNodeCheckbox(TreeNode treeNode , bool value)
{
     treeNode.Checked = value;
     foreach(var subNode in currentNode)
     {
         SetTreeNodeCheckbox(subNode, value);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, buddy!! I just missed this logic ;-) In fact, I implemented this in some other scenario.

Answer (score 1):

First replace the below code

```
setAllCheckedTrue(treeView1);
```

with the below instructions

```
foreach(TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes)
{         
  setAllCheckedTrue (node);
}
```

This will change the type of parameter sent to function "setAllCheckedTrue" that will become a node and not a treeview, and update the setAllCheckedTrue function with the below function

```
private void setAllCheckedTrue(TreeNode node)
{
    node.Checked = true;
    foreach(TreeNode childnode in node.Nodes)
    {   
    setAllCheckedTrue (childnode);
    }
}
```

Cordially

Comment: It is resolved already! Although, thank you for responding!